# Ordering the results in a controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-order-by

I have the following action in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(String id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext();
    List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id).ToList();

    return View(rl);
}
```

How can I add order by clause to my query to order the records on x.RecordName field?

Comment: You really shouldn't put your db logic inside an action on the controller.

Comment: are you referring to the where clause or order by?

Comment: Actually, both. These belong inside DAL (database access layer). Your controller shouldn't know anything about how to get the data or where it comes from, that's why this have to be abstracted. Whole point of MVC is to have a decoupled architecture. Controller exists to create a response that will be sent to the client, taking the in-parameters, parsing the request and returning a view based on that (and passing the model/viewmodel if necessary).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `OrderBy` extension method e.g.

```
public ActionResult Details(String id)
{
    MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext();
    List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id).OrderBy(x => x.RecordName).ToList();

    return View(rl);
}
```

This will order the items by their `RecordName` alphabetically.

Comment: Thanks! One more thing - if I want to order by two fields (for example RecordName and then RecordTitle), how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by two fields, you can do this:

```
List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id)
                                .OrderBy(r=>r.RecordName)
                                .ThenBy(r=>r.RecordTitle)
                                .ToList();
```

`ThenBy` method performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in ascending order according to a key.If you call `OrderBy` multiple times, it will effectively reorder the sequence completely two times

Answer (score 0):

You can use OrderBy for eg

```
public ActionResult Details(String id)
{
MyRecordContext rc = new MyRecordContext();
List<MyRecord> rl = rc.MyRecords.Where(x => x.RecordID == id).OrderBy(x => x.RecordName ).ToList();
return View(rl);
}
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. (This post was flagged by at least one user, presumably because they thought an answer without explanation should be deleted.)